# What is the difference between "i DD 12345" and "i: DD 12345"?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Is there a difference between the following two statements:

```
i: DD 12345

    section .data:
i DD 12345
```

Comment: No. The colon is optional.

Comment: For Microsoft and probably Intel assemblers, | i: dd 12345 | is not allowed. Labels with colons are not allowed in the data section, and in the code section you can't have | i: dd 12345 | either, but you could have | i: | on one line and | dd 12345 | on the next line, but the i: will represent an offset in the code segment, while with | i dd 12345| the i represents a double word with content value 12345.

Comment: re: `section .data:` instead of `section .data` - that's a bug. 
 [Segmentation fault in x86\_64 assembly writing into section .data:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69249191)